# Adding a double-click feature to jQuery Picklest plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I like the looks of the jQuery [picklist plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/picklists/) over the older jquery-picklists, but the older one has the double click add feature, that I also want, that allows me to add an entry, without having to use the arrow keys.  Has anyone added this or a similar feature to the new plugin?  Any recommendations on how to implement a similar feature ?  Or maybe a better widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`jquery-picklist`**](http://plugins.jquery.com/picklist/) plugin, as of version 0.11.0, supports double-clicking to move an item to the opposite list. You may want to check it out.

Disclaimer: I'm the plugin author. I suggest taking a look at other jQuery picklist plugins as well and find the one that best suits your needs.